# After removing an harmful item I get a KSOD (black screen, cursor works) when I log in

Tags: black-screen-of-death

Just today I read a post stating that Java has a leak; so, I ran a [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](http://ninite.com/malwarebytes/ninite.exe) scan and it found an harmful item and thus I deleted that item. After restarting my computer from a prompt, my Lenovo v570 laptop now turns on with a black screen and a movable cursor.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> does not work.

I have tried in safe mode and it turns on properly. So, I tried to do what others suggested on other forums, which was to "roll back my graphics driver". After trying that, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Windows needs to re-stabilize itself after the threat removal.  I have seen this before, where it can take a few minutes to "rebuild" itself.  If it seems to take a while, you can always force a chkdsk and/or run Windows Startup Repair.

If it's a graphics driver issue, you should try to find the most recent driver you can.